# How to access an element from 2nd level parent?

Tags: html, css

Maybe I am wrong, correct me if so. My problem is similiar to a solution when we are using a sibling css selector `.firstclass + .secondclass` which search's for the `.secondclass` from `.firstclass`'s parent.

I need to access an element with a classname `.btn` which actually is not in the same parent element as `.btn.active`. Here is a HTML:

```
<div class="row parent2">
  <div class="col-xs-3 parent1">
    <button class="btn btn-default">One</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3 parent1">
    <button class="btn btn-default active">Two</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3 parent1">
    <button class="btn btn-default">Four</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3 parent1">
    <button class="btn btn-default">Five</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need to style a next (Button Three) element of currently active button (Button Two).

There is no such as `nth-parent`.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: You can't do this with CSS because you can't get to a higher element. From `.active` you can't select the parent element and thus you can never select the `.btn` after the active `.btn`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change the element having `active` class to the upper one.

So, instead of having:

```
  <div class="col-xs-3 parent1">
    <button class="btn btn-default active">Two</button>
  </div>
```

Change to:

```
  <div class="col-xs-3 parent1 active">
    <button class="btn btn-default">Two</button>
  </div>
```

Then you will have an access to siblings.

Comment: I was hoping there will be a solution without doing it like that.
Thank you, I will do it in that way within jQuery

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with CSS because you can't select a parent element, which you try: `.active` => parent `.parent1` => next `.parent1` => child `.btn`.

You can do it with jQuery instead:

```
$('.active').parent().next().children('.btn')
```

Demo: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tepsterd/)

Comment: Thank you, I thought there will be a solution for this by doing it in pure CSS, but if there is no option, I will use a jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the following.

```
$('.active').closest('div').next().children('.btn');
```

```js
$('.active').closest('div').next().children('.btn').css('color', 'blue');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row parent2">
  <div class="col-xs-3 parent1">
    <button class="btn btn-default">One</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3 parent1">
    <button class="btn btn-default active">Two</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3 parent1">
    <button class="btn btn-default">Three</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3 parent1">
    <button class="btn btn-default">Four</button>
  </div>
</div>
```